# Oracle and TSQL statement NO LOCK

Tags: oracle, t-sql

```
select max(Key) from MyTable with(nolock)
```

I have this T-SQL statement but need to use one statement for both SQL Server and Oracle as well, of course the “with (nolock)” is not recognised by Oracle. Is there a way having this statement that will run on both databases. By either an Oracle ignoring the “with (nolock)” or only Sqlserver using this part of the statement or a way or coded that both with understand.

The reason why I am using No lock is because multiple users are accessing the same table and I need to find the max value during the transactions.

Oracle does things a bit differently so I do not have to worry about table locks.

Comment: Why do you need to have one query? If those database don't speak the same language, you will need two queries.

Comment: You don't need NOLOCK at all. Your MAX may be inconsistent if you do.

Comment: One app different connections string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your queries are doing different things. What are the semantics of the query supposed to be? Is it supposed to return `max(Key)` including the effect of uncommitted transactions as your SQL Server version indicates? If so

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
select max(Key)
from MyTable;
```

Is the same semantics. <strike>The syntax should work fine on both AFAIK.</strike>

If instead you want the last committed `max(Key)` you would need to change the SQL Server database to use read committed snapshot isolation by default so it behaves more similarly to Oracle. Or alternatively you could achieve similar semantics with `ROWLOCK,READPAST` hints but then you are back to needing two different queries.

Comment: The UNCOMMITTED only COMMITTED is available in Oracle This does react the same in SQL Server sit waits for lock to be released.Dirty inconsistent data is fine. I also tried to use Read Only same result waits for lock.

Comment: @icecurtain - Ah didn't realise that Oracle doesn't support `UNCOMMITTED`. You need to use snapshot isolation in SQL Server then or have 2 different queries.